# Is it possible to get the teddy bear/malfunction on the first mystery box/magic wheel/3D Printer activation?

Tags: call-of-duty-series

It's never happened to me; I always get the 'teddy bear' after about 3-6 activations. But is it at all possible for it to happen in the first activation in any Call of Duty Zombies game-mode?

Comment: I've never seen it happen on like the first 3 rolls ever.

Comment: Yeah, I think that'd be kind of evil if it happened super early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [COD Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Box#Teddy_Bear):

> The chances of the Teddy Bear appearing in the box increase depending on how many times the box has been used in its current location. The Teddy Bear will never appear on the first three uses of the box. The fourth through seventh uses have a 15% chance of choosing the Teddy Bear. Uses in the range of eighth to twelfth have a 30% chance, and any rolls after that have a 50% chance. When the box is in the starting location, however, the Teddy Bear will always appear after eight uses.

It is not possible for it to appear within the first three rolls (as I previously hypothesized), and therefore, it is not possible for it to happen on the first.